# What is one NTP interval?

Tags: c, time, kernel, ntp

I am trying understand how kernel maintains the system time. I going through this file timekeeping.c in the kernel source tree.
What I have understood so far is,

- for maintaining system time, kernel relies on a counter/timer from the processor. It stores the time in timespec data structure, refereed as xtime, which has been updated by the timer periodically (based on interrupts)
- If you read or set time, xtime variable comes into action

Mean while I have problem understanding the following variables

```
/* Number of clock cycles in one NTP interval. */
   cycle_t cycle_interval;
/* Number of clock shifted nano seconds in one NTP interval. */
    u64 xtime_interval;
```

What is one NTP interval implies here?

Comment: What is its value, one NTP interval?

Comment: I dont know the answer but you need to be more specific,which kernel?,which platform?

Comment: in general, the RTC is hardware, kept alive by the battery on the motherboard.  The OS is (typically and for historical reasons) interrupted on a periodic basis (usually every 1/18 second,*the NTP interval* again for historical reasons) The interrupt handler for the system clock updates the system time.   However, note that modern OSs that are 'online' correct the system clock from some `time` server.